# Why does the following EF to SQL fails to filter by name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following EF to SQL statements and a "filterBy" which is a List with 1 item. the first produces a list of 1 as expected but the second does not. I thought the sql produced is functionally equal.

```
var adList = dbCtx.AttackDetails
.Where(d => filterBy == null || filterBy.Contains(d.Name))
.Where(d => d.StartedAt != null)
.Where(d => isCompleted ? (d.Status != 5) : (d.Status == 1))
.Include(t => t.StatusNavigation)
.ToList();
```

If I write the code as follows, then it returns multiple elements as if the where clause "dbQuery.Where(d => filterBy.Contains(d.Name))" didn't execute. I thought these are both functionally equal.

```
var dbQuery = dbCtx.AttackDetails;

if (filterBy != null)
{
    dbQuery.Where(d => filterBy.Contains(d.Name));
}

dbQuery.Where(d => d.StartedAt != null)
    .Where(d => isCompleted ? (d.Status != 5) : (d.Status == 1))
    .Include(t => t.StatusNavigation);

var adList = dbQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Change `dbCtx.AttackDetails.AsQueryable()` and inside if change to `dbQuery = dbQuery.Where....`

Answer (score 3):

You are not persisting the parameters of your `.Where` queries. Try something like:

```
var dbQuery = dbCtx.AttackDetails.AsQueryable();
if (filterBy != null)
{
  dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(d => filterBy.Contains(d.Name));
}
```

You basically want to build up an `IQueryable` until you have all the conditions you want, and then `.ToList()` it when you're ready to actually surface the results.

Comment: You cannot assign iqueryable to dbset

Comment: You just need to type dbQuery as `IQueryable<AttackDetail>` instead of using `var`.

Comment: Not me but OP... I know this

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is building a single expression.

Your second example is not re-assigning the `IQueryable` variable so the `Where` clauses are effectively doing nothing. It will return all rows because:

```
var dbQuery = dbCtx.AttackDetails;
// dbQuery is never re-assigned so...
var adList = dbQuery.ToList(); // returns all AttackDetails.
```

The simple fix as Jonathan pointed out:

```
var dbQuery = dbCtx.AttackDetails.AsQueryable(); // Cast as IQueryable<AttackDetail>

if (filterBy != null)
{
    dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(d => filterBy.Contains(d.Name));
}

dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(d => d.StartedAt != null)
    .Where(d => isCompleted ? (d.Status != 5) : (d.Status == 1))
    .Include(t => t.StatusNavigation);

var adList = dbQuery.ToList();
```

Alternatively, since `Where` clauses are all ANDed together, you can group all of the mandatory filters at the start and append any optional ones afterwards:

```
var dbQuery = dbCtx.AttackDetails
    .Include(t => t.StatusNavigation);
    .Where(d => d.StartedAt != null)
    .Where(d => isCompleted ? (d.Status != 5) : (d.Status == 1));

if (filterBy != null)
    dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(d => filterBy.Contains(d.Name));

var adList = dbQuery.ToList();
```

It just helps keep the code a bit more compact.

I'm curious that this expression: `.Where(d => isCompleted ? (d.Status != 5) : (d.Status == 1));` actually resolves down to SQL. Somewhat neat if it does, it's normally something I would have extracted out into a separate if/else expression.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your issue is in your selector, i.e. `filterBy.Contains(d.Name)`. Before we get to the code, let's use common sense. Should the given entity appear in the search results, when the given filter is supplied?

```
 ENTITY   FILTER    RETURN?
============================
  ALAN  |  ALAN   |   YES
  AL    |  AL     |   YES
  ALAN  |  AL     |   YES    <----
  AL    |  ALAN   |   NO     <----
```

The first two are obvious, but let's look at the last two. When **the name contains the filter**, it should be returned. When **the filter contains the name**, it should not be returned (because the filter is more restrictive than the entity's name)

Now let's look back at the code:

```
filterBy.Contains(d.Name)
```

With this code, you would return the entity if the filter contains the name. If the entity is "AL" and the filter is "ALAN", the above filter logic would return the entity, and that's not right.

[Here's a fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s7LEdM) where you can play with the input values and can see if the example entity would be returned or not. Seeing it in action makes it click, more so than me explaining it verbally.

To fix the problem, you need to invert your code:

```
d.Name.Contains(filterBy)
```

*For the fiddle example, that would be `entityName.Contains(filterBy)`.*

If you fill in the truth table for this logic, you will see that it exactly matches the common sense exercise we did in the beginning.

---